# Arrays changing value when saving to / opening h5 files

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, h5py

I am trying to train a CNN classifier in Caffe on image data however when I save my images to h5 format to insert into my first Caffe layer, there is a small chance one or two of my array's will have one or two of their pixel values changed.

I check my array's pixel values before I save them to h5 files and then compare them to when I open them

```
for image in images:
    if np.max(image) > 1 or np.min(image) < 0:
         print np.max(image), np.min(image)

with h5py.File(path, 'w') as f:
    f['data'] = images
    f['label'] = labels

h5_file = h5py.File(filename, 'r')

images, labels = list(h5_file.keys())

images = list(h5_file[images])
labels = list(h5_file[labels])

for image in images:
    if np.max(image) > 1 or np.min(image) < 0:
         print np.max(image), np.min(image)
```

I expect my arrays coming out to not contain any values above 1 or below 0 (the images are normalized). I perform a check just prior to saving them (I never find an array outside of my range of 0-1) to a h5 file. However, there appears to be a chance that when I open the h5 file, some of the images will have a couple of pixel values changed. Their values will not be between 0 and 1, but instead appear to be of the order of magnitude of ~ 10^100 or -10^100.

I have no clue why, I am using python 2.7 with h5py version 2.7.1